# In Java, how to make a method able to accept variadic parameters or Set of parameters without duplicating the code of implementation?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I'm looking for a way so that I can use the same portion of code to deal with parameter passing through Set or variadic parameters. e.g.

```
public void func(String...strs){
    for (String str : strs){
        //Deal with str
    }
}
```

According to the spec, the func will also supports:

```
public void func(Set<String> strs){
    for (String str : strs)
        //Deal with str
    }
}
```

}

Both the processing code are identical, how can I merge to a single implementation? Please kindly advise.

Thank you.

Regards,
William

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no efficient solution to the problem you pose. Varadic functions receive an array. No magic wand will wave itself and convert from `java.util.Set` to array.

Further, the semantics don't match, since Set is unordered and forbids duplicates, and array is ordered and permits dups.

you can define the second function as

```
public void func(Set<String> strs) {
   func(strs.toArray(new String[strs.size()]);
}
```

and pay for the allocation.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void func(String...strs){
    func(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strs)));
}

public void func(Set strs){
    for (String str : strs)
        //Deal with str
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think such a constructor exists for HashSet.

Comment: Yes harto, if String...strs can be represented as a Collection, the problem is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is implement your Set version like this:

```
public void func(Set<String> strs) {
    return func(strs.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Thx Mike, so I can only choose to use the toArray() method~

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but I think it's better to do it that way because you don't have to convert a complete collection.

```
public void func(String...strs){
    for (String str : strs){
        func_impl(str);
    }
}

public void func(Set strs){
    for (String str : strs)
        func_impl(str);
    }
}

public void func_impl(String str){
    //Deal with str
}
```

Plus: No conversion.

Minus:  A lot of call (to func_impl) if the collection is large.